# Getting hosted content bytes using Microsoft Graph returns HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We've been trying to **download the bytes of hosted content attachments** embedded in Team messages using the **Microsoft Graph**, but we encounter **HTTP 403 Forbidden** errors. It happens when the authenticated user becomes a member of an existing team using the Graph, then uses the [GET chatMessageHostedContent beta API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-get-hosted-content-bytes-for-an-image) on a hosted content attachment.

These are the reproduction steps:

- In the Teams browser or desktop application:

  1. Log in to your Office 365 tenant using a licenced user **A**,
  2. Create a new public team,
  3. In this team, create a new public channel,
  4. In this channel, create **many hosted content attachments in multiple messages**: copy-pasted images using the Snipping Tool, code snippets.
- In the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) or any C# application that uses the Microsoft Graph Beta nuget package:

  1. Log in using to the **same tenant**, but as another user **B**, who is **at least Teams Administrator and SharePoint Administrator**
  2. [Add this user as a member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of new newly created team
  3. [Get all the messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
  4. [Download the bytes of all hosted content attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-get-hosted-content-bytes-for-an-image)

You will get HTTP 403 Forbidden errors on all hosted content attachments downloads.

**There is a way to make it work**, but it involves *"manual work"* that cannot be done programmatically:

- As user **B**, open the channel in the Teams application UI (in Fiddler, we see HTTP 403 but at some point it starts to work)
- Or, instead of joining the group using the Graph, still as user **B**, join the team using the Teams application UI
  [image: Join team using UI]

Each of these two solutions seems to trigger a permission synchronization process that cannot be done using the Graph only. Once they're done, downloading the hosted content bytes using the Graph works.

We also noticed that we don't get HTTP 403 for hosted content embedded in the *General* primary channel for some reason.

Is there anything we've missed?

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. I am discussion this issue with internal Team.

Answer (score 1):

My team was facing this same issue and ended up rectifying it by switching from delegated permissions on a service account to using application permissions.

At the time of writing this the Get hosted content api is a protected API and required approval to use. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis